# In which JSF Phase does the cdi conversation start?

Tags: java, jsp, cdi

In what JSF phase does a transient CDI conversation get promoted to a long standing conversation. I am assuming that this happens in the invoke application phase since this is this is where the Conversation.begin() method can be called.

I am looking to implement a mechanism to start start conversations in the JSP phase listener. By configuring certain view ids as the starting point of a conversation. So in the JSF listener i want to be able to check to see if a conversation needs to be started if current view id is the same as the configured view id. Kind of similar to conversation-begin tags within pages.xml a feature that does not exist with seam 3.